# Version 4.0 of Swagger Swashbuckle introduces a new big white bar at the top of swagger pages

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

Could someone explain what this white bar is? Why is there nothing in it? If there is supposed to be something in it, how do I add it? If it's not needed, how do I get rid of it? Using the Swashbuckle nuget package 4.0.1 in an ASP.NET Core 2.1 WebAPI.

[image]

Here is a link to the [swagger.json](https://a.uguu.se/1URuYMTXUXCi_swagger.json) (i couldn't add it directly here, SO said that there was too much code)

Thanks

ETA:
So after reading through the comments, someone pointed me to a swagger page with the schemes filled in. I looked at the JSON and noticed this:

[image]

Mine doesn't have this. I am going to assume that's my issue. How do I use swashbuckle to insert this information?

Side note: If this information isn't present in the Swagger.JSON... should that white bar simply be hidden?

Comment: Can you post a full screenshot? This bar is where the HTTP/HTTPS scheme selector and "Authorize" button are supposed to be.

Comment: OK updated with the html of the element

Comment: Can you also post the contents of your swagger.json file?

Comment: updated to include the swagger.json

Comment: The link to your json is broken

Comment: Try testing your json on the PetStore sample like this: http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://api.gettyimages.com/swagger/docs/3

Comment: i used a file upload service that expires after 24 hours. reuploaded

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that big white bar at the top is to specify schemas. If you don't explicitly specify a schema, it sits blank. I have opened up an issue about this on swagger's github repo. I believe that this bar should disappear if it serves no purpose.

To fill this bar in with something useful, you have to add something like this to your project:

```
app.UseSwagger(c=>
{
    c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swagger, httpReq) => swagger.Schemes = new[] { "http", "https" });
});
```

Comment: This no longer works in v5. Empty big white bar still persists though.

Answer (score 1):

The empty white bar [was fixed](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5029) in Swagger UI v. 3.20.1. The white bar appeared if the definition had no `schemes` and no `securityDefinitions`.

[Andy's workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53340346/113116) for adding `schemes` with `PreSerializeFilters` can be used in the meantime until Swashbuckle updates its bundled Swagger UI to the version that includes the fix.

Comment: They broke this yet again in v5.0. Now the PreSerializeFilters method doesn't work as `swagger.Schemes` is gone. Man these swagger people LOVE breaking changes.